# Partition type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF for the primary macOS partition after uninstallation of Ubuntu Linux

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, partition, data-recovery

A few month b ack I installed Ubuntu Linux on my early 2015 MacBookPro, but after not using it for a while I decided to uninstall it. After that, when I tried to boot my mac   I was brought to the GNU Grub screen and was not able to boot to MacOS. I managed to install macOS Yosemite on another partition I created earlier. After some research I found out, that I could probably fix my problem changing the partition type. Sadly I tried many solutions I found on forums but none worked for me. I included some screenshots with some additional info.My goal is to boot to the Partition or at least recover my data. Thank you for your help[image: Disk Utility][image: Terminal][image: Terminal]

Comment: Please use search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ffffffff or see the sidebar Related column.

Comment: I did search but nothing worked for me

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also have a look at the [Ask Different question checklist](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist)

Comment: DenizXYZ: If you still can not fix your Mac, you can post a comment and the question may be reopen. However, I think you will have to explain further what "nothing worked for me" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have Yosemite installed you do not have any SIP restrictions. This means you can download and install [gptfdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/), then use the `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0` command to change the partition type. I would assume since there is no recovery partition immediately after `disk0s2` that the `disk0s2` was type `Apple_APFS`. In terms of `gdisk`, this would be type `af0a`. The entries needed to the interactive command `gdisk` to change the partition type to `Apple_APFS` are given below. Here, I assume the partitions are stored in the order shown from the `diskutil` output you posted. You can verify this by viewing the output from the `p` command.

| Entry | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `p` | Command | Print the partition table |
| `t` | Command | Change a partition's type code |
| `2` | Parameter | Partition number |
| `af0a` | Parameter | Hex code for APFS partition type |
| `w` | Command | Write table to disk and exit |
| `y` | Parameter | Confirm write and exit |

> **Note: Yosemite existed before APFS. Therefore, You should assume Yosemite will not recognize the APFS partition type. This includes the `diskutil` command. However, the current version of `gdisk` will recognize the APFS partition type**

Other possible partition types are included below.

| `diskutil` Type | `gdisk` Type | `gpt` Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Apple_HFS` | `af00` | `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |
| `Apple_Boot` | `ab00` | `426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |
| `Apple_CoreStorage` | `af05` | `53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |
| `Apple_APFS` | `af0a` | `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |

### References

- [GPT fdisk Tutorial](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)